# python function to split a list by indexes

Tags: list, function, python-2.7, split, indexing

I am trying to build an efficient function for splitting a list of any size by any given number of indices. This method works and it took me a few hours to get it right (I hate how easy it is to get things wrong when using indexes)

Am I over-thinking this?

Code:

def lindexsplit(List,*lindex):

```
index = list(lindex)

index.sort()

templist1 = []
templist2 = []
templist3 = []

breakcounter = 0
itemcounter = 0
finalcounter = 0


numberofbreaks = len(index)
totalitems = len(List)

lastindexval = index[(len(index)-1)]
finalcounttrigger = (totalitems-(lastindexval+1))

for item in List:

    itemcounter += 1

    indexofitem = itemcounter - 1

    nextbreakindex = index[breakcounter]

    #Less than the last cut
    if breakcounter <= numberofbreaks:

        if indexofitem < nextbreakindex:

            templist1.append(item)

        elif breakcounter < (numberofbreaks - 1):

            templist1.append(item)

            templist2.append(templist1)

            templist1 = []

            breakcounter +=1

        else:

            if indexofitem <= lastindexval and indexofitem <= totalitems:

                templist1.append(item)

                templist2.append(templist1)

                templist1 = []

            else:

                if indexofitem >= lastindexval and indexofitem < totalitems + 1:

                    finalcounter += 1

                    templist3.append(item)

                    if finalcounter == finalcounttrigger:

                        templist2.append(templist3)


return templist2
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks jonrsharpe ! :)